# TextField text overlap in tableview

Tags: qt, qtquick2

I have a `TableView` which has a text delegate. While editing the text component is replaced by a `TextField`.The problem is all the row is replaced by a `TextField` and when I try to type a long text the text overlap like in the photo:

How can I avoid this behavior?

[image: Text overlap]

**PS:code is the same as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016278/tableview-with-qsortfilterproxymodel**

Comment: Maybe show some code?

Comment: Sure it's the same code in this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016278/tableview-with-qsortfilterproxymodel

Comment: You can set maximum width to your textEdit or try to change tableView column size on text change, you can calculate the font size with `QFontMetrics` and to apply it on the table column

Comment: it's a textfield, there is no such property or you are talking  about maximum length?